# Specific formatting for DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to replicate a similar program in terms of formatting a DataGridView.
This is how I want it to look:

[image: Image of an attendance sheet]

I've attempted this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    ' Initial Styling of Cell Selection
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
        Next
    Next
    Dim current As Integer = 0
    current = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex
    Dim target As Integer = current
    Dim looping As Boolean = True
    While looping
        If target = 0 Then
            looping = False
        End If
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(target).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
        target = target - 1
    End While
    current = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
    target = current
    Dim column As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex
    looping = True
    While looping
        If target = 0 Then
            looping = False
        End If
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(target).Cells(column).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End While
End Sub
```

I've also set the selection mode to `CellSelect` and changed that color to a light blue like in this picture. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bi4R.png)

I've probably screwed up my code somewhere but my VS has a bug where it will stop and put the application to break but it won't show me the exception.
Anybody have any ideas what I can do from here to maybe fix it?

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line and check that it behaves as you expect. If you haven't debugged, it's too soon to be posting here. If you have debugged then you have more specific information available to you that you have provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Lokks ok you misst a target = target - 1 in your row loop

```
    target = current
    Dim column As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex
    looping = True
    While looping
        If target = 0 Then
            looping = False
        End If
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(target).Cells(column).Style.BackColor =        Color.Orange
        target -= 1
    End While
```